# How to change fonts in Kod?

Tags: macos, text-editors, fonts

I started using this new text editor called Kod (runs on Mac OS 10.6):

http://kodapp.com/

It's very very fast, I'm a poor programmer and I don't have money to pay for TextMate, this might be the closest to TextMate that I've used. (TextMate cost around $50).

The problem is.... Where is the preferences window? Where can I set the font size? I need to make it bigger, that's it... Does anyone know how to do that?

EDIT: I think they haven't implement them yet... From their discussion in google group.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Locate the Kod application bundle (e.g. `/Applications/Kod.app`) and *Show Package Contents*.

Navigate to `/Contents/Resources/style/` and copy `default.css` to your desktop. Rename the file to `kod.css`.

Open Terminal and enter the following command:

```
defaults write se.hunch.kod style/url ~/Desktop/kod.css
```

Open the `kod.css` file in an editor and change the `font-size` attribute of `body` to change text size. `font-family` determines which font is used.

If Kod is running, select *View » Reload Style*.

Enjoy.

<sup>Store your modified CSS file anywhere you want. Desktop is just an example -- just remember to tell Kod via `defaults` where it's located.</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I did not even move it to Desktop, I just edited the css file right in the application package contents. You're a winner!

Comment: @the_great_monkey This'll get overwritten every time you update the application. But it's probably a good idea in this stage of the application's development, with the possibility of major changes to these files.

Comment: If you edit the style sheet directly in Kod, it will update the styles as soon as you save the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Yet. It's still only a very early beta. They haven't added that feature quite yet. And, there isn't a preferences window at all right now.